# Type-level monoid-like operations for generalizing indexed monads?

Tags: haskell, monads, type-families, type-level-computation

To motivate this question, let's first recall a bog-standard Hoare-Dijkstra-style indexed monad, and the example instance of an indexed writer monad.

For an indexed monad, we just require type alignment on `(i)bind`s:

```
class IMonadHoare m where
    ireturn :: a -> m i i a
    ibind :: m i j a -> (a -> m j k b) -> m i k b
```

and then just to show that this is usable, let's implement an indexed writer monad:

```
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
import Control.Category

newtype IWriter cat i j a = IWriter{ runIWriter :: (a, cat i j) }

instance (Category cat) => IMonadHoare (IWriter cat) where
    ireturn x = IWriter (x, id)

    ibind (IWriter (x, f)) k = IWriter $
        let (y, g) = runIWriter (k x)
        in (y, g . f)
```

And it really is a writer-like monad, since we can implement the usual methods:

```
itell :: (Category cat) => cat i j -> IWriter cat i j ()
itell f = IWriter ((), f)

ilisten :: (Category cat) => IWriter cat i j a -> IWriter cat i j (a, cat i j)
ilisten w = IWriter $
    let (x, f) = runIWriter w
    in ((x, f), f)

ipass :: (Category cat) => IWriter cat i j (a, cat i j -> cat i j) -> IWriter cat i j a
ipass w = IWriter $
    let ((x, censor), f) = runIWriter w
    in (x, censor f)
```

OK, so far so good. But now I'd like to generalize this to other kinds (heh) of indices. I thought it would work to simply add associated type families for the type-level monoid operations, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, PolyKinds, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Data.Kind

class IMonadTF idx (m :: idx -> Type -> Type) | m -> idx where
    type Empty m :: idx
    type Append m (i :: idx) (j :: idx) :: idx

    ireturn :: a -> m (Empty m) a
    ibind :: m i a -> (a -> m j b) -> m (Append m i j) b
```

So, does this work? Well, you can use it to define something where `Empty`/`Append` is non-indexed, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.TypeLists

newtype Counter (n :: Nat) a = Counter{ runCounter :: a }

instance IMonadTF Nat Counter where
    type Empty Counter = 0
    type Append Counter n m = n + m

    ireturn = Counter
    ibind (Counter x) k = Counter . runCounter $ k x

tick :: Counter 1 ()
tick = Counter ()
```

**But now can we recreate our `IWriter` example?** Unfortunately, I haven't been able to.

First of all, we can't even declare `Empty`:

```
data IWriter cat (ij :: (Type, Type)) a where
    IWriter :: { runIWriter :: (a, cat i j) } -> IWriter cat '(i, j) a

instance (Category cat) => IMonadTF (Type, Type) (IWriter cat) where
    type Empty (IWriter cat) = '(i, i)
```

This, of course, fails because the type variable `i` is not in scope.

Let's change `Empty` into a `Constraint` instead, and recreate the `Counter` instance just to validate it:

```
class IMonadConstraint idx (m :: idx -> Type -> Type) | m -> idx where
    type IsEmpty m (i :: idx) :: Constraint
    type Append m (i :: idx) (j :: idx) :: idx

    ireturn :: (IsEmpty m i) => a -> m i a
    ibind :: m i a -> (a -> m j b) -> m (Append m i j) b

newtype Counter (n :: Nat) a = Counter{ runCounter :: a }

instance IMonadConstraint Nat Counter where
    type IsEmpty Counter n = n ~ 0
    type Append Counter n m = n + m

    ireturn = Counter
    ibind (Counter x) k = Counter . runCounter $ k x

tick :: Counter 1 ()
tick = Counter ()
```

Now we can at least write down the definition of `IsEmpty (Writer cat)`, but in the code below, `ireturn` still doesn't typecheck. It is as if the defintion of `IsEmpty` isn't used to solve constraints:

```
instance (Category cat) => IMonadConstraint (Type, Type) (IWriter cat) where
    type IsEmpty (IWriter cat) '(i, j) = i ~ j

    ireturn x = IWriter (x, id)
```

> Could not deduce `i ~ '(j0, j0)` from the context `IsEmpty (IWriter cat) i`

Similarly, we can try to enforce the alignment in the middle by adding a constraint for appending:

```
class IMonadConstraint2 idx (m :: idx -> Type -> Type) | m -> idx where
    type IsAppend m (i :: idx) (j :: idx) :: Constraint
    type Append m (i :: idx) (j :: idx) :: idx

    ireturn :: (IsEmpty m i) => a -> m i a    ibind :: (IsAppend m i j) => m i a -> (a -> m j b) -> m (Append m i j) b
```

But then that fails for `IWriter` in a similar way:

```
instance (Category cat) => IMonadConstraint2 (Type, Type) (IWriter cat) where
    type IsAppend (IWriter cat) '(i, j) '(j', k) = j ~ j'
    type Append (IWriter cat) '(i, j) '(j', k) = '(i, k)

    ibind (IWriter (x, w)) k = IWriter $
        let (y, w') = runIWriter (k x)
        in (y, w' . w)
```

> Could not deduce `j ~ '(j1, j0)`
>         from the context `IsAppend (IWriter cat) i j`

**Is it because `IsEmpty` and `IsAppend`  defined "pointwise"?**

Comment: Please give the three new `IMonad` classes you propose different names, so we can properly discuss them.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: discuss away!

Comment: Thanks. I will try later...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr: it looks like you're looking for monads indexed by categories.

Compilable gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/04039e4ca6f7a3740281e4e3583ae971

---

`IMonadHoare` is not equivalent to `IMonadTF` (aka. graded monad, see [effect-monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/effect-monad-0.8.1.0/docs/Control-Effect.html)).

In particular, with `IMonadTF` (graded monads) you can bind any two computations, their indices get appended together, whereas with `IMonadHoare` (indexed monads) you can only bind computations with matching indices. Therefore you can't easily encode an arbitrary `IMonadHoare`, such as `IWriter`, as an `IMonadTF` because there is no meaning to `bind` when the indices don't match.

This kind of "partially defined composition" for `IMonadHoare` is reminiscent of categories, and indeed we can generalize both `IMonadHoare` and `IMonadTF` with monads indexed by arrows of a category, instead of pairs of indices or elements of a monoid. Indeed, we can see examples of categories in both classes:

1. Pairs `(i, j)` can be seen as arrows of a category in which `i` and `j` are objects (so there is exactly one arrow between `i` and `j`, the pair `(i, j)`, although it doesn't really matter what it is, only that there is exactly one);
2. Monoids are categories.

Here's the class of monads indexed by a category `c :: k -> k -> Type`; this class includes the definition of the category `c`, via the associated types `Id` and `Cat` that correspond to your `Empty` and `Append`. It looks actually pretty much the same as `IMonadTF`, except that you have a category `c :: k -> k -> Type` instead of a monoid `idx :: Type`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, TypeFamilies, PolyKinds, DataKinds #-}

import Control.Category as C
import Data.Kind

class CatMonad (m :: forall (x :: k) (y :: k). c x y -> Type -> Type) where
  type Id m :: c x x
  type Cat m (f :: c x y) (g :: c y z) :: c x z

  xpure :: a -> m (Id m) a

  xbind :: m f a -> (a -> m g b) -> m (Cat m f g) b
```

Here's the category of pairs I mentioned earlier. Between every object `i` and `j` (in some set/type `k`), there is one arrow `E` (the name doesn't matter, only that there is only one). It can also be visualized as the complete graph with vertices in `k`.

```
data Edge (i :: k) (j :: k) = E
```

We can now define `IWriter` as a `CatMonad`. It's a bit finicky, you have to put `i` and `j` explicitly or they get quantified in the wrong place for the `CatMonad` instance head. Otherwise there isn't much trouble. Nothing really depends on `E`,
it's merely a placeholder for its type, which contains the indices that matter `i` and `j`.

```
newtype IWriter cat i j (q :: Edge i j) a = IWriter { runIWriter :: (a, cat i j) }

instance Category cat => CatMonad (IWriter cat) where
  type Id (IWriter cat) = E
  type Cat (IWriter cat) _ _ = E

  xpure a = IWriter (a, C.id)
  xbind (IWriter (a, f)) k =
    let IWriter (b, g) = k a in
    IWriter (b, f C.>>> g)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work seamlessly with GHC 8.6.3 at least: if I try to set `hello :: IWriter (->) Bool Bool E String; hello = xpure "hello"`, then I get "Expected type: `IWriter (->) Bool Bool 'E String`
        Actual type: `m0 Bool Bool (Id m0) [Char]`
      The type variable `m0` is ambiguous", unless I write it as `xpure @_ @_ @(IWriter (->)) "hello"` which is not really going to be usable...

Comment: Actually, I have the `Counter` example working now: https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/d0b8204d9e35750c91179f6468e30eb9

Comment: I've discovered that I can use `RebindableSyntax` to good effect to get rid of most of those visible type applications, basically defining a "monadic kit"  local to each definition: https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/d0b8204d9e35750c91179f6468e30eb9

Comment: Nifty tricks! The ambiguity error might be a bug; there might also be a very good explanation which escapes me. That's the first time I've come across a class indexed by a polykinded type. It might be a good idea to bring this up on GHC's bug tracker. A possible workaround is to flip the dependency, so that the ends of arrows are computed from the arrow:  `CatMonad (c :: Type) (k :: Type) (m :: c -> Type -> Type)` with `To, From :: c -> k`, and then add appropriate equality constraints on `xpure` and `xbind`.

Comment: I might update my answer or create another one later if I get around to work on this more.

Comment: I am **almost** there, just need to figure out why I can't use `catMonad` as intended to provide a local kit: https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/937cee74bb0eda3a761c780b0237b2d1

Comment: I'm starting to think it's not a bug, the problem is that matchable type constructor application is not dependently typed. Based on that, one solution is to introduce a fundep `c -> m` to resolve the ambiguity; a bit strong, but workable: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/7331df3abee0aceacd3d9a74b567f54c

Comment: I'd say this is coming along nicely: https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/5f0d35a825a94e523380468b46b2f810

Comment: Also, I've managed to tease out a GHC panic by playing around: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/16946

Comment: The gists look fun. I wonder how awful it can get when we need to refer to category laws to type programs.

Answer (score 1):

(There is no reason to put a tuple into `IWriter`; I'm just going to use this

```
data IWriter (cat :: idx -> idx -> Type) (p :: (idx, idx)) (a :: Type) where
  IWriter :: a -> cat i j -> IWriter cat '(i, j) a
```

)

You've write

```
ireturn x = IWriter x id
```

for all version of the class. However, `IWriter x id :: forall i. IWriter cat (i, i) a`, while you need `IWriter cat m a` (where `cat`, `m` and `a` are arguments to `ireturn`). `(,) _ _` is not `m`, period. You cannot write a constraint that proves this, either, because then `i` needs to be an argument to `ireturn`, but it's a typeclass method, so that can't be allowed. That aside, the correct `IMonad` is really the last one (`IMonadConstraint`, both `1` and `2`, together).

```
class IMonad (m :: idx -> Type -> Type) | m -> idx where
  type IsEmpty m (i :: idx) :: Constraint
  type IsAppend m (i :: idx) (j :: idx) :: Constraint
  type Append m (i :: idx) (j :: idx) :: idx
  ireturn :: IsEmpty m i => a -> m i a
  ibind :: IsAppend m i j => m i a -> (a -> m j b) -> m (Append m i j) b
```

You need to assert an axiom:

```
data IsTup (p :: (i, j)) where IsTup :: IsTup '(x, y)
isTup :: forall p. IsTup p
isTup = unsafeCoerce IsTup
```

The statement `forall (p :: (i, j)). exists (x :: i) (y :: j). p ~ '(x, y)` is neither provable nor disprovable in Haskell, so we can take it as an axiom like this, if we need it. It seems "true" enough.

```
instance Category cat => IMonad (IWriter cat) where
  type IsEmpty (IWriter cat) '(i, j) = i ~ j
  type IsAppend (IWriter cat) '(_, i) '(j, _) = i ~ j
  type Append (IWriter cat) '(i, _) '(_, j) = '(i, j)
  ireturn :: forall i a. IsEmpty (IWriter cat) i => a -> IWriter cat i a
  ireturn x | IsTup <- isTup @i = IWriter x id
  ibind (IWriter x w) f | IWriter y w' <- f x = IWriter y (w >>> w')
  -- IWriter :: forall cat p a. forall i j. p ~ '(i, j) => a -> cat i j -> IWriter cat p a
  -- IsTup   :: forall     p  . forall x y. p ~ '(x, y) =>                 IsTup       p
  -- in ibind, the two matches on IWriter prove that the two type-level tuple
  -- arguments are actually tuples
  -- in ireturn, you need to split that behavior out into it's own type IsTup,
  -- make forall p. IsTup p an axiom, and use it to show that the argument i
  -- is also really a tuple
```

Comment: I think you can avoid the `isTup` axiom by changing `IsEmpty` to `isEmpty (IWriter cat) ij = ij ~ ('(Fst ij, Snd ij), Fst ij ~ Snd ij)`